# SSL site and browser warning

Tags: ssl, https

I have an e commerce site naturalvape.us using wordpress. hostgator is where its hosted.

I have a ssl certification installed. My issue my site shows a caution sign and says it is unsecured. The guys at hostgator gave me a link to this site to force ssl/https. Apparently some type of code is needed to redirect to the secure site.

Why do I have a warning in the browser?

How can I redirect the site to https?

Comment: It already redirects to the HTTPS version of the site. The actual error message says "The certificate is not trusted because no issuer chain was provided", which means (I *think*) that somewhere in the HostGator panel you need to add the certificate(s) for the issuer chain. Since this isn't a programming problem it should be asked on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) if you need help.

Answer (score 11):

To expand upon Boan's comment, you certificate chain is malformed.

You are only sending the end entity (server) certificate; and you need to send both the end entity certificate and two intermediate certificates required for Comodo.

You need to send the intermediate certificates to avoid the ["which directory" problem](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Transport_Layer_Protection_Cheat_Sheet#Rule_-_Always_Provide_All_Needed_Certificates). Its a well known problem in PKI. That's what clients are experiencing - they don't know where to go to get the missing intermediate certificate.

Here's how you can check for it:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect naturalvape.us:443 -showcerts
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=0 OU = Domain Control Validated, OU = PositiveSSL, CN = naturalvape.us
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
...
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=PositiveSSL/CN=naturalvape.us
   i:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIFUDCCBDigAwIBAgIRAOIeCA8uCx0hLc8AQSHiak8wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAw
gZAxCzAJBgNVBAYTAkdCMRswGQYDVQQIExJHcmVhdGVyIE1hbmNoZXN0ZXIxEDAO
...
t3d8prtVxlUd9xp0AEXPOLI1uKQlDKNCOQlHFrINkZbwwg6hmomiFXx5IpfVSb9U
XIqr/cZP7xtD2oiYCJ2giJ7dHLU=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
---
Server certificate
subject=/OU=Domain Control Validated/OU=PositiveSSL/CN=naturalvape.us
issuer=/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
...
```

Notice there's one certificate present with a subject of `CN=naturalvape.us` (subject is the "s:" in the display). The issuer is `CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA`, but that intermediate certificate is missing (issuer is the "i:" part in the display).

To fix this, you need to fetch *COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA* from [[Intermediate #2 (SHA-2)] Comodo RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA](https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Default/Knowledgebase/Article/View/970/0/intermediate-2-sha-2-comodo-rsa-domain-validation-secure-server-ca).

The intermediate certificate is already PEM encoded. Take your server certificate, and append the *COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA* intermediate. That means there will be two certificates in the file. They will look like:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
<server certificate>
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
<intermediate certificate>
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Plug that into your site under the server certificate.

---

Unfortunately, its not enough to add just *COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA*. You also need to add *COMODO RSA Certification Authority*. Its another missing intermediate certificate. You can get *COMODO RSA Certification Authority* from [[Intermediate #1 (SHA-2)] COMODO RSA Certification Authority](https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Default/Knowledgebase/Article/View/966/106/intermediate-1-sha-2-comodo-rsa-certification-authority).

So they will look like:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
<end entity/server certificate>
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
<intermediate certificate #2>
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
<intermediate certificate #1>
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

---

Users (relying parties) will still need to have/trust the issuer of the *last* missing intermediate (the *last* missing intermediate is *COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA*). The issuer of the last missing intermediate is `CN=AddTrust External CA Root`, and it should be built-in to the browser or one of those `cacerts.pem` packs.

---

Once you concatenate the two missing intermediates certificates with the server certificate (and upload it), you can test as follows.

First, download the trust anchor. Its `CN=AddTrust External CA Root`, and it can be found at [[KMCS] AddTrust External CA Root](https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Default/Knowledgebase/Article/View/962/0/kmcs-addtrust-external-ca-root).

Second, run `openssl s_client` to verify. Notice the addition of the `CAfile` option and the *"Verify result OK (0)"*.

```
$ openssl s_client -connect naturalvape.us:443 -CAfile addtrustexternalcaroot_kmod.crt 
CONNECTED(00000003)
...
Start Time: 1407558078
Timeout   : 300 (sec)
Verify return code: 0 (OK)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your images are loading through http. Go to your wordpress settings, and change both the site urls so they start with 'https'.

http://userguide.expand2web.com/wp-content/forum-image-uploads/don/wordpress-site-url.jpg